# Does this chain seem short? Does this photo indicate any obvious drivetrain issues?

Tags: chain, gears, drivetrain, learning

[image]

Addition.
Yes this is the large-large chainring.
The shifting is rather poor but I have not tuned high, low and B, tension etc.
Thank you

I recently moved to a larger
chainring.
The shifting seems unresponsive enough.

Does the position of the derailleur seem like the chain is to short?

Thank you

Happy cycling

Comment: And by "unresponsive enough" did you mean "responsive enough?" I.e. is is shifting OK or are you having poor shifting?

Comment: Moving to a larger chainring without adding links to the chain doesn't sound right.

Comment: Post has been updated

Answer (score 4):

Are you on your largest chainring in this picture? (Chainrings being the large cogs by your pedals).

I see the chain deflecting slightly between the bottom of the lower jockey wheel (on the right in your picture), top of upper jockey, and bottom of the largest cassette cog:

[image]

This means the derailleur is taking slack out of the chain and could in theory stretch a little further (though you don't want it fully extended with that red line I drew becoming a straight line).

So if you're in your largest chainring I think you're OK. If you're not, your chain is probably slightly too short. It doesn't look to me like it can spool out enough remaining chain to go to a larger chainring.

Comment: This is probably correct. Most properly we should add links if we sized up the chainrings, but there is some error margin built into the system. Also, the chain might have been slightly too long to begin with.